# Filtering a data frame containing worldwide data and filtering only US states?

Tags: data-manipulation, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing, data-filtering

I have a dataframe that contains the cols State which has the name of states and n number of date cols for confirmed covid cases. How can i filter the data frame so that i only have 50 states, the US territories, the District of Columbia, and the US as a whole. I know i can just type all the states. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

I have tried using the typing the states by hand, but im wondering if there is a way maybe using RE?